# Running bundle exec rake inside cron cannot find specific version of rake

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron, rubygems

I am setting up cron to run some rake tasks for my ruby on rails server. They are generated by whenever and look like this:
`* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake my:task --silent >> /var/www/log/cron.log 2>&1'`

`bundle` and `rake` executables seem to be found, but inside cron.log I find this error:

```
bundler: failed to load command: /usr/local/bin/rake (/usr/local/bin/rake)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize'
...
...
```

As I can see it tried to load rake-12.3.2, which is a correct version, from `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems`, which is not a correct path, because there is no rake-12.3.2. Correct version of rake is under another path `/usr/local/bundle/gems`, but I have no luck setting this path for cron to use.

I have tried adding `GEM_PATH="/usr/local/bundle/gems"` to cron file, but it doesn't work.

I am not using rvm or rbenv, ruby is installed directly.